# API is not returning OAuth token instead permission page

Tags: c#, api, rest, oauth

I am trying to upload video on personal amazon cloud using REST API. The problem is that i ask for access token using client id at very first step. it opens login page although permission is already given.

Go to this url
    https://developer.amazon.com/appsandservices/apis/experience/cloud-drive/content/restful-api-getting-started

I am following this method **Authorization Code Grant**

after i login it redirect to desired redirection page. I am making tool for windows in c#.
All i want is to directly get to the redirection link